# Why can't pass my variable to applescript?

Tags: applescript, automator

The screenshot shows how I'm trying to do this. I can't seem to pass a captured variable onto applescript. I'm new to applescript, so it's likely something very basic that's tripping me up.

Basic syntax or something like that. At present, the text '(input02)' is being passed, rather than the variable.

Have googled, no luck. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few things wrong with the **Automator** *workflow* and the **AppleScript** *code* in the OP.

In the **AppleScript** *code*:

In the second **Run AppleScript** *action*, of the image included in the OP, the *code* should be as follows:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set input02 to (input as text)
    delay 2
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        execute front window's active tab javascript ¬
            "document.getElementById('title').value = '" & input02 & "';"
        execute front window's active tab javascript ¬
            "document.getElementById('wmd-input').value = 'body copy goes here';"
    end tell
end run
```

- In the first `execute` *line*, `'(inputs02)'` is changed to `'" & input02 & "'`, thus allowing it to actually pass the *value* of the `input02` *variable*. As was originally coded, it was passing a literal `input02` not the *value* of the `input02` *variable* because it was captured between two quotes and the parentheses are not necessary. In this use case, concatenating the *variable* with *ampersands* and not enclosing it in quotes makes it a *variable* not a *literal*. (You'll see the *variable code highlighting* in the image below.)

In the **Automator** *workflow*:

In the image below, note the **Options** settings on two of the *actions* where the 
 **[√] Ignore this actions input** is checked. This creates a disconnect between it and the previous *action*, thus ignoring its `input`. See the highlights, where compared to between the *action* below, it's no longer connected.

The *actions* which have the  **[√] Ignore this actions input** checked should not be directly passing any information to the next *action*, as they are supposed to be independent of the subsequent *action* in this use case.

[image: Automator Workflow]

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks for the detailed answer.